# removing words inputted by the user using stream and filter in java

Tags: java, exception, java-8, java-stream

```
public class FilterText {
    Path path;
    String p;
    List<String> word=new ArrayList<String>();
    public FilterText(String[] words) {
        this.path=Paths.get(words[1]);
        p=words[1];
        this.word.addAll(Arrays.asList(words));
        word.remove(0);
        word.remove(0);
    }

    public void DoTheFilter() {
        Stream<String> line = null;
        try {
            line = Files.lines(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         List<String> newtext=line.collect(Collectors.toList());
         newtext.stream().filter(str -> word.contains(str));

          try {

                 File f=new File(p);
                 FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,false);
                 for ( String s : newtext) {
                 fw.write(s);
                 fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
                 }
                 fw.close();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
    }
```

Hello, I'm facing a problem with the filtering part. Basically my code asks input from the user to input a command, for example :
Filter (path here) (words to remove from the text file)

Everything is working fine but the filter part. I'm asked to stream the file and then overwrite the filtered version. Streaming and rewriting is working fine as I've tested it, I only have a problem with the actual filtering, hope you can help :) 
The problem is located in the method DoTheFilter, after streaming the file.

Comment: `newtext.stream().filter(str -> word.contains(str));` does not do anything. Insert the filter operation into the previous stream operation *before* you collect the items into a `List`. Don’t forget to close the stream afterwards, or better, use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). And don’t reinvent the wheel. Write the list using [`Files.write(path, lines)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-)

Comment: And generally, rethink the way you are dealing with exceptions. When your `Files.lines(…)` fails, you will run into a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you @Holger, I have fixed my code based on what you've suggested and it worked, now all i need to figure out is how to treat the stream word by word and not line by line :)

Comment: Since you want to write the result back as lines, processing a particular line word by word is a sub-operation. E.g. `line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\W+")).filter(w -> !word.contains(w)) .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))`, this literally processes the line as stream of words, but has the disadvantage of replacing all non-word characters by a space.

Answer (score 1):

All the content inside the `DoTheFilter` method can be merged into one `try-catch`:

```
try {
    List<String> newtext = Files.lines(path)
        .filter(str -> word.contains(str))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    File f = new File(p);
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f, false);
    for (String s: newtext) {
        fw.write(s);
        fw.write(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    fw.close();
} catch (IOExceptione) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note the following:

- With separation of `Stream` you risk NPE on the `line.collect(Collectors.toList());`. This should be handled in the try block as long as you want to avoid programming with `null`.
- `newtext.stream().filter(str -> word.contains(str));` doesn't do anything since the stream is not closed with a terminal operation, such as `forEach`, `collect`, `reduce` etc. The intermediate operations will not take effect.
- Catch `IOException` rather than more general `Exception`.